# Getting data from NSURLSessionTaskDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to use `NSURLSession` with a `DataTask` and a `Delegate` but I can't find a way to convert the data obtained by the `didReceiveData` method into a string.

This is the code that I'm using, the problem that I'm experiencing is that I get some data but when I try to convert this data into a string I get `nil`, while the expected result would be the source of the page that I've requested.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

    var session:NSURLSession?
    var data = NSMutableData()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        session!.dataTaskWithRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")!)).resume()
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?){
        var str = NSString(data: NSData(data: self.data), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println(data) // IT PRINTS DATA CONTENT
        println(str) // IT PRINTS nil :(
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask, didReceiveData data: NSData){
        self.data.appendData(data)
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked the error to make sure you are receiving the data properly?

Comment: Yes this is a simplified version of my real code. The error is `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the received string data is not UTF8 encoded. Try NSASCIIStringEncoding.

Comment: You're right... now my question is why?! I supposed that UTF8 was the standard encoding set for web requests/responses.

Comment: If you are downloading www.google.com page there are HTTP headers at the beginning and only the body data is UTF8.